# type Error : undefined is not an object (evaluating ' this.state.deals.lengh')

Tags: react-native

I have a problem to get data from some server whit to react native. 
at the first I use web API . in this case I use Axios(I think is better for the catch, maybe  wrong!)
now I can not show this data or maybe  I can't get it, I don't know, please help me.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import ajax from '../ajax';
import Deallist from './deallist';
import axios from 'axios';
const API = 'https://bakesaleforgood.com'
const DEFAULT_QUERY = '/api/deals/'
class app extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true })
        axios.get(API + DEFAULT_QUERY)
            .then(result => this.setState({
                deals: result.data.deals,
                isLoading: false
            }))
            .catch(error => this.setState({
                error,
                isLoading: false
            }))

        // const deals = await ajax.fetchInitialDeals();
        // this.setState({deals:deals})
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            deals: [],
            isLoading: false,
            error: null,
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {
                    this.state.deals.length > 0
                        ? < Deallist deals={this.state.deals}></Deallist>
                        : <Text style={styles.header}> Bakesale </Text>
                }
            </View>
        );
    };}const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    header: {
        fontSize: 40,

    }})export default app;
```

deallist.js:

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet,FlatList } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import DealItem from './dealitem';
class Deallist extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    deals: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.list}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.deals}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <DealItem deal={item}/>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    paddingTop: 50,
  }
})
export default Deallist;
```

dealitem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text,StyleSheet,Image } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
class DealItem extends Component {
    static propTypes={
        deal:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image
        source={{uri: this.props.deal.media[0]}}
        style={styles.image}
        ></Image>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    image:{
        height:150,
        width:'100%',
    }
})
export default DealItem;
```

I get the type error for state.deals.lenght

Comment: when I use wifi, I cant get data from the API. how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data object doesn't have `deals` property, it's an array of object. use `result.data` instead.

```
componentDidMount = () => {

this.setState({ isLoading: true }); // you set this true by default, instead of setting it here.

 axios.get(API + DEFAULT_QUERY)
  .then(result => this.setState({
    deals: result.data,
    isLoading: false
  }))
  .catch(error => this.setState({
    error,
    isLoading: false
  }))

}
```

[Working Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/supportive-salsa)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here :

> `this.state.deals.length > 0
>   ? < Deallist deals={this.state.deals}></Deallist>
>    : <Text style={styles.header}> Bakesale </Text>`

you have 2 way :

- in render check if this.state.deals is defined or not

> ((typeof this.stat.deals !='undefined') && (this.state.deals.length >
>   0))

- define deals as an empty array state in componentWillMount

> ```
> componentWillMount(){
>      this.setState({deals:[]});
> }
> ```

axios is a good package but also you can use fetch function exists in ES6

Comment: in here `result.data.deals` deals is undefined, please see my answer below.